# How can I 'specialize' a React component in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Assume I have some functional component like

```
function MyComp({a, b, c, d, e, f}: any) {
  ...
}
```

How can I make a specialization of this where I supply "a" and "b" but leave users of my specialization to decide the remaining values.  So without knowing anything more about `MyComp`, is there a way to:

```
const MySpecial: FC<Omit<ParamsOf<MyComp>, "a", "b">> = 
    (props) => <MyComp a="foo" b="bar" ...props />
```

such that when another user later uses `<MySpecial>`, their type completion shows that c, d, e, and f are available, but a and b aren't.

Note my goal is to do this such that if tomorrow someone adds g, h, and i to `<MyComp>`, my specialization still works without any changes

Comment: Sure: https://tsplay.dev/mA8d8N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React provides a type to get the prop types of a component: `ComponentProps`.

```
const MySpecial: React.FC<
    Omit<React.ComponentProps<typeof MyComp>, "a" | "b">
> = (props) => <MyComp a="foo" b="bar" {...props} />;
```

You can then get the type of your original component and omit `a` and `b`.

[image]

Looks good!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoczAVwDsNgJa4BZATwGFcwAKAb3JwhcFABpBwgEbjhcNDOEATBUKQq4mcQF8AXHAGyUegM4wowWgHMKsySbMXrEoWj0pabG0rcevqn57OGgEUWgCU+kFEMNRQzAA8isAAbgB88QD0SWmhlGhMpqxsAMpgSGjAKAA2esjoMAB0AGIc8UEA8iDAMPF1GA1c4ExItDAACjhgxvEwbGUQmEWDYKmiBCj4cAA+BJL4qeSpcAC8cDxgk8YRx0fx7Msix-iYEBCbkk+SKFCbfA3-FwgUy0cAyqVIQA)